# Selenium Web driver - Java how to handle the 3rd party control?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I want to know that how to handle the third party control in selenium web driver and how to play with elements on Create lead which are shown on the pop up. I have tried with getWindowHandles:

```
 Set<String> winids= driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> itrate=winids.iterator();
        String first_window=itrate.next();
```

[image: By clicking on the New button Create Lead is open which is third party control]

Comment: Your popup seems to me to be a fake popup/window. Simply try to access the elements by they ID in the same window. Does it work?

Comment: @LaurentG no it doesn't work. :( please any other suggestion.

Comment: Can post the html for the text area and popup

Comment: @TestAutomationEngr
<tr>
<td> Description*: </td>
<td>
<textarea id="txtInstructions" class="schedule_notes" style="height: 95px; width: 294px !important;" cols="20" rows="2" name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$txtInstructions"></textarea>
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" class="error_message" style="display:none;">* missing</span>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: I think JSExecutor should work for your req. Sample code - JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById(elementid).type('sometext')");  Similarly you can use click and other DOM operations.